# how to make option selected by default in react

Tags: reactjs

I am using this.state.something in option tag to make it selected default.
but it is showing me error at this.state.editusertype

```
<select name="usertype" className="form-control" value={this.state.editusertype}>
 <option value="">Select</option>
 <option value="Employee" {this.state.editusertype == "Employee" ? "selected" : ""} >Employee</option>
 <option value="Manager" {this.state.editusertype == "Manager" ? "selected" : ""}>Manager</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a default option, set a default value for your `select` tag. It should correspond with a matching option. See sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/young-pine-zmpvr

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    editusertype: "Manager"
  };

  handleOnChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      editusertype: event.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <select
          name="usertype"
          className="form-control"
          onChange={this.handleOnChange}
          value={this.state.editusertype}
        >
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option value="Employee">Employee</option>
          <option value="Manager">Manager</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`handleOnChange()` is used to change the value upon selection of a different item.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select).

```
const options = [
  { value: '', label: 'Select' },
  { value: 'Employee', label: 'Employee' },
  { value: 'Manager', label: 'Manager' }
];

return (
    <Select
        name="usertype"
        className="form-control"
        options={options}
        value={this.state.editusertype}
     />
);
```